# C# Get TestCases by TestCaseSource - Reading textfile

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I try to get my nunit TestCases by reading a textfile, which contains a TestCase per line. I'm using the TestCaseSourceAttribute in that case.

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestSelection")]
//TestMethod


public static object[] TestSelection()
{
    var amountOfTestCases = GetAmountTestCases(@"path\TestCases.txt");
    var result = new object[amountOfTestCases];

    for (var i = 0; i < amountOfTestCases; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new object[] { GetTestCase(i, @"path\TestCases.txt") };
    }

    return result;
}
```

With `GetAmountTestCases()` I get lines of text within a textfile and `GetTestCase()` reads the specific line of text to get my TestCase.

```
public static int GetAmountTestCases(String path)
{
    var lineCount = 0;
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            lineCount++;
        }
    }
    return lineCount;
}

public static String GetTestCase(int lineNum, String path)
{
    var lineCount = 0;
    String testCase = String.Empty;
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            if (lineCount == lineNum)
            {
                testCase = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                lineCount++;
            }

        }
    }
    return testCase;
}
```

After building the .dll contains test modules with 'null' as content. I cant even Debug without a specific TestCase within my Code.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a complex way of going about it, the following code works for me:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("GetMyFileData")]
//Method

public static string[] GetMyFileData()
{
    var path = @"C:\temp\MyFile.txt";
    return File.ReadAllLine(path)
               .ToArray();
}
```

Please double check if your path is correct.

If it is a relative path to the file that is deployed on build, check if it is configured correctly: its `Build Action` should be something like `Content` and `Copy to output directory` should be `Copy of newer` or `Copy always`